# Clang fails to find const template member function from base class

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, compiler-bug

The following C++ file:

```
struct Base {
    template <typename T, int = 42>
    void f(T &&) const {}
};

struct Derived: Base {
    template <typename T, typename X = typename T::asdf>
    void f(T &&) const {}

    using Base::f;
};

int main() {
    Derived const cd;
    cd.f('x');
}
```

compiles well with GCC but not with Clang:

```
$ g++-7.3.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-7.2.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-6.4.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-5.4.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
$ g++-4.9.4 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
$ clang++-4.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
test.cpp:15:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'f'
        cd.f('x');
        ~~~^
test.cpp:8:14: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = char]: type 'char' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
        void f(T &&) const {}
            ^
1 error generated.
$ clang++-5.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
test.cpp:15:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'f'
        cd.f('x');
        ~~~^
test.cpp:8:14: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = char]: type 'char' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
        void f(T &&) const {}
            ^
1 error generated.
$ clang++-6.0 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -Wall -Wextra
test.cpp:15:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'f'
        cd.f('x');
        ~~~^
test.cpp:8:14: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = char]: type 'char' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
        void f(T &&) const {}
            ^
1 error generated.
```

Why doesn't it compile with Clang? Is my code correct? Is this a compiler bug? A bug in the C++ standard?

Comment: It's never lupus, and it's never a compiler bug. There's no match for `cd.f('x');`  'char::asdf` is not a thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JiveDadson: Surely it's a compiler bug with one of them - either the code snippet violates the standard and it should be an error (compiler bug with GCC for compiling successfully) or the code snippet is fine and shouldn't error (compiler bug with Clang for not compiling successfully).

Comment: The code is bad. It doesn't use Base because the user code specifically says Derived.

Comment: Today I'm out of phase... yes: you've added `using Base::f`... sorry... forget what I've said. I don't know if a SFINAE disabled function cover the base class (as think liliscent) or not. Sorry again.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a gcc bug.

According to the `using-declarator` (emphasis mine):

[[namespace.udecl]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#1)

> The set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator is found by performing qualified name lookup ([basic.lookup.qual], [class.member.lookup]) for the name in the using-declarator, excluding functions that are hidden as described below.
>
> ...
>
> When a using-declarator brings declarations from a base class into a derived class, member functions and member function templates in the derived class override and/or hide member functions and member function templates **with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (if any) in a base class** (rather than conflicting). Such hidden or overridden declarations are excluded from the set of declarations introduced by the using-declarator.

In your case, the base class `f()` should be hidden, and invisible to the derived class.

Another important point is, the effect of `using` is at name-lookup stage, before SFINAE. Thus whether there is a SFINAE has no impact.

Comment: Sad that template arguments is not part of that list :-/